# Azure monitor alert for CPU usage > 80% for 30 minutes or more

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

I am trying to create an Azure monitor alert for CPU usage >= 80% for 30 mins or more

I've attached a screenshot of the condition for the alert rule. Under Evaluated based on does the Aggregation granularity (Period) mean that the alert will be triggered if the CPU average is greater thank 80% for 30 minutes or more?

---

[image]

Comment: Text is almost always better than an image

Answer (score 2):

```
Under Evaluated based on does the Aggregation granularity (Period) mean that the alert will be triggered if the CPU average is greater thank 80% for 30 minutes or more?
```

Yes, the conditions whatever you are given for the monitor alert is correct.

Based on the condition what you have given for the azure monitor alert, you are asking Azure Monitor to run an evaluation for every 5 minutes and average the CPU percentage (usage) over the previous 30 minutes, then fire an alert if that number is greater than 80% of the CPU usage.